# Can we drag and drop legend or series from one linechart to another in echart?

Tags: echarts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkw46.png)

I using multiple instances of chart. Is there a way to drag legend or series from one chart to another and plot it?

Comment: Hello.. Is it possible to drag the legend? Is so, can you share some code here?